# Implementing Overtone Series(Harmonic Series) using Audiokit Sampler

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am a beginner with Audiokit. I am trying to implement Overtone Series Effect on harmonies using Audiokit. I am using Midi Sampler along with AKappleSequencer to play different notes. As in the overtone series I will be required to change or adjust the frequencies or pitches of the sounds in cents at different positions so I am not sure and struggling to find how to achieve that.

```
  for mid in arrbeats{

      var midi = Double(mid["note"] ?? 0)
      var adj = Double(mid["adj"] ?? 0)
      adj = adj / 100 // adjustment in cents

      midi = midi + adj

      sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber(exactly: midi) ?? MIDINoteNumber(midi), velocity: 60, position: AKDuration(beats: pos), duration:AKDuration(beats: chord.mNote.raw()))

      setUpCallback(position: pos,type: 2)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many ways to achieve this type of thing, but they are not trivial to implement. Here are some ideas for you:

- Learn about AudioKit's built in microtonal scales. We have an AKTuningTable that you can load with your own array of frequencies to map midi [notes](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/79cebe3ff8acc64e743b9e9536693c193e478eb4/AudioKit/Common/Internals/Microtonality) to:
  This technique is used to create the hundreds of interesting retuning in [AudioKit](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKitSynthOne/tree/master/AudioKitSynthOne/Tunings) Synth One:
- Use oscillators instead. Oscillators frequencies can be set directly. To sequence them, use the sequencer triggering an AKCallbackInstrument that then triggers your oscillators with the appropriate logic.

Comment: Thank you. One more question, are the units of pitchbend in sequencer in Cents or Semitones?